# replace a value in file with jq (one liner)

Tags: shell-script, jq

I want to replace the value of "CTE_LG_LL_OE" from "warn" to "ready"

```
{ "abcd": { "aav": "on", "vvg": "iio7890_APPID", "ct": "b-tte", "eSL": true, "it": "https://%ght%.mjk.com/", "tpo": "i-1", "pd": false, "pm": false, "pr": "" }, "en": { "CTE_LG_LL_OE": "warn", "S_G_EL_OD": "INFO", "G_LG_EL_OVE": "info" }, "EN_HTTPS": false }
```

I am able to find the same in file using the below command , but how do I replace it with one liner command.

```
jq '.' /abc/temp/config.json | grep CTE_LG_LL_OE
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To *get* the key's value, you would use a JSON-aware tool, like `jq` rather than `grep`.  You would do this for a few reasons:

1. The value that you are extracting may be *encoded*.  The `jq` tool would decode this for you if you use it with the `-r` (`--raw-output`) option.
2. Using `grep` makes no distinction between values and keys, so you may accidentally extract data that you did not plan to extract.

Extracting the value of the `CTE_LG_LL_OE` key in the top-level `en` entry:

```bash
jq -r '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE' file
```

Setting the value to the string `ready` and writing the resulting document to the file `new-file`:

```bash
jq '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE |= "ready"' file >new-file
```

The `|=` operator is the "update operator" and it takes a "path" to a key to the left and a new value for the key on the right.

To set the value from a shell variable:

```bash
jq --arg newval "$newvalue" '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE |= $newval' file >new-file
```

This creates a `jq` variable called `$newval` from the shell variable `newvalue`, which we then use in the `jq` expression.  The value in the variable will automatically be JSON-encoded by `jq`.

For readability, space things out a bit (assuming this is part of a shell script, since the question is tagged with [shell-script](/questions/tagged/shell-script)):

```bash
jq --arg newval "$newvalue" \
    '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE |= $newval' file >new-file
```

To do in-place editing of the file (`jq` does not support in-place editing by itself):

```bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

cp file "$tmpfile" &&
jq --arg newval "$newvalue" \
    '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE |= $newval' "$tmpfile" >file &&
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

As a once-liner:

```bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp); cp file "$tmpfile" && jq --arg newval "$newvalue" '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE |= $newval' "$tmpfile" >file && rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

---

If you're not sure of *where* in the document structure the `CTE_LG_LL_OE` key is located and just want to update the values of *all* `CTE_LG_LL_OE` keys that have the value `warn`:

```bash
jq '
    (
        .. |
        select(type == "object" and .CTE_LG_LL_OE? == "warn").CTE_LG_LL_OE
    ) |= "ready"' file
```

This examines all keys and values recursively in the whole document.  It finds all objects that has a `CTE_LG_LL_OE` key with th evalue `warn` and updates these to instead be `ready`. The newlines are only for readability.

The value could be taken from a shell variable as before:

```bash
jq --arg newval "$somevariable" '
    (
        .. |
        select(type == "object" and .CTE_LG_LL_OE? == "warn").CTE_LG_LL_OE
    ) |= $newval' file
```

This could obviously be combined with doing in-place editing too, as show in the first half of this answer.

Comment: but this is not an one liner command

Comment: @Alex You mean the last one? Just put the two lines on the same line if you want: `newvalue=ready; jq --arg newval "$newvalue" '...' etc.`  Note that the assignment to the shell variable `newvalue` is irrelevant to the actual updating of the value in the JSON file (which is done on a single line already).  That value can be a pre-existing shell variable value, something read from a user, or the output from some other program.

Comment: @Alex Almost any shell command, no matter how complicated, can be written on a single line, if you're happy writing unreadable code.  Also, why would you ever want to write "one-liners" in a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

With your example content in file.json, the following one-liner works:

```bash
cat file.json | jq '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE = "ready"' | tee file.json
```

To break this down:

1. `cat …` copies the contents of file.json to standard output (stdout).
2. `|` sends this output to the standard input (stdin) of the next command.
3. `jq '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE = "ready"'` has what jq calls a ‘filter’ (`'.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE = "ready"'`, assigning that specific value to that specific key) but does *not* specify any input file(s). This causes `jq` to read its input from stdin.
4. `| tee` sends the output from `jq` to the `tee` command, which writes it to both stdout *and* the named file.

I found this question after being puzzled by the behaviour of `jq` myself. For some reason (compare answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964305/write-output-to-a-file-after-piped-to-jq) output redirection does *not* work, nor does having `jq` do the file read itself. In short, none of the following work; any of them will truncate file.json, leaving it totally empty:

```bash
jq '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE = "ready"' file.json >file.json

jq '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE = "ready"' file.json | tee file.json

cat file.json | jq '.en.CTE_LG_LL_OE = "ready"' >file.json
```

It's possible some of the standard command-line options would alter this behaviour.